# JPA Hibernate Mapping Partitioned Table to an Entity

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, partitioning

I have a Spring Boot application where I connect to a PostgreSQL database. I have a table that I created with two columns that act as a primary key (`id` and `active_flag`) and the table is partitioned on one of them. When I map the tables to Java entities, I always get an error on the main table that it is missing, but the partitioned tables I can map them normally without any errors.
Is this the normal behaviour? Can we not map the main partitioned table?

Below is my table and class mapping

```
create table test_kc (
    test_id integer not null,
    name text not null,
    active_flag boolean not null default true,
    created_at timestamp not null default now(),

    constraint test_kc_pk primary key (test_id, active_flag)
) partition by list (active_flag);

create table test_kc_active partition of test_kc for values in (true);
create table test_kc_inactive partition of test_kc for values in (false);
```

EntityId.java

```
@Data
public class EntityId implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private Boolean activeFlag;
}
```

TestKcEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_kc")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@IdClass(EntityId.class)
public final class TestKcEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "test_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "active_flag", nullable = false)
    private Boolean activeFlag;

    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;
}
```

As can be seen in the code above, when table name is `test_kc`, I get the below error when I run my application: `Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [test_kc]`.

When I replace the table name to `test_kc_active`, it works fine and the application runs normally.

Comment: Not a solution by any means, perhaps a temporary bypass: if you give `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` the value `none`, it skips the schema validation and then it works.

Comment: It turns out, when using partitioning, I cannot create an entity on the main table, I can only create it on the partitioned tables. It seems the main table is considered as an abstract table, so technically it doesn't exist physically per se. My alternative would be to use inheritance partitioning.
It seems my options are either make do with the partitioned table entities only, or I have to switch to inheritance partitioning to create an entity for the main table as well.

Comment: FYI: With Hibernate 6 `PARTITIONED TABLE` is included in `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` and therefore no workaround is need any more.

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution would be to set the hibernate parameter `hibernate.hbm2ddl.extra_physical_table_types` to `PARTITIONED TABLE`. With this Hibernate will not only accept tables and views as Entity `@Table` values.

See also https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#settings-schema

Comment: FYI: With Hibernate 6 `PARTITIONED TABLE` is included in `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` and therefore no workaround is need any more.