# How can I use hibernate validation with a partitioned table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, partitioning

I created a table with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
    id BIGSERIAL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (id);

CREATE TABLE my_table_2023_10 PARTITION OF my_table FOR VALUES FROM (1) to (100000);
```

application.yml:

```
server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT:12332}
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pg_test
    username: postgres
    password: 12345
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate.ddl-auto: validate
```

Entity

```
@Entity(name = "my_table")
@Data
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.12'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.spring.playground'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.11'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'
}
```

When I start my app, I get the following exception:
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [my_table]

It works fine if I replace hibernate.ddl-auto: validate by hibernate.ddl-auto: none

With ddl-auto: none hibernate inserts and updates work fine.

I've found a similar question : [JPA Hibernate Mapping Partitioned Table to an Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76768766/jpa-hibernate-mapping-partitioned-table-to-an-entity)

But it does not have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you have to change a little bit `Entity Class`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
}
```

> The @Table annotation allows you to specify the details of the table
> that will be used to persist the entity in the database. The @Table
> annotation provides four attributes, allowing you to override the name
> of the table, its catalog, and its schema, and enforce unique
> constraints on columns in the table.

In your case it is the reason, because `MyEntity` is not table name in database.

**Update**

As a fix

You have to add next one Param in config file

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.extra_physical_table_types=PARTITIONED TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I still get this error - Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [my_table]

Comment: is `pg_test` the database where `my_table` are located ?

Comment: Yes.  It is not a problem with a table name or schema. Because only validation doesn't work. INSERT and UPDATE work fine.

Comment: change it to `update` or do you have schema in that database where are located table ? if it is it can help you ``spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schemaName``

Comment: I mean that SQL commands like INSERT and UPDATE are executed by Spring on repository save, etc.


That means that hibernate somehow inserts new records into this table and doesn't throw an error.


So DB is fine. Repositories are fine. But only validation doesn't work with a partitioned table.


When I set hibernate.ddl-auto: update.


This gives an error :Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "my_table" already exists.

Comment: To fix it if it is about partitioned table: `hibernate.hbm2ddl.extra_physical_table_types=PARTITIONED TABLE` to your properties and now all tables wii be found.

Comment: Thanks! You solved my problem! I created hibernate.properties file in the same directory as application.yml. And added your property.

Comment: I will update the answer and then you can accept it and also upvote for future if someone will have the same question/problem

Comment: FYI: With Hibernate 6 `PARTITIONED TABLE` is included in `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` and therefore no workaround is need any more.